# Grouping problem with postback in SPGridview

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I have a SPGridView with a custom CheckBox Template in it. To access the value of the checkbox I have created the SPGridView in Page_Init method. It was working fine. I also have grouping in the grid. It was working fine till I made any postback in the page. To overcome that I created my own custom GridView and overrided the LoadControlState event. Now the problem is when I use this Custom Grid in my page the LoadControlState event occurs after the Init event and hence the grid doesnt render on the page. When i keep it in Page_Load it works fine but my custom checkbox template creates a problem then. How do I get both the custom Checkbox Template and grouping with postback in the SPGridview working properly???

Please help as this is really getting me stuck.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I had to clear my grid columns every time and add new columns in page load . This way the SPGrid is working perfectly fine with grouping and custom template even on postback